# What do you call a section where specific (same kind of) items/foods etc are placed such as in supermarket?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I just would like to know for a personal reason.

Such as meat section, or menswears' section, or toys' section etc?

(As I age older, I will change the work. I will be tested for "daily conversation").

P.S I would like to particulatlly know about the general terms used in the U.S But other countries' will be fine to know. Please specify your country of your origin such as from the U.K or Australia etc in the answer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you asking for the general term (which is just **section** or **department**), or for the name of each specific section?

Comment: @stangdon Thanks. My concern is about general terms, or if there is anything else for specific use, please let me know.

Comment: @stangdon For example, would you say, "meat area"?

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the link. But I'm not talking about foods only as I from the start asked "items" in the headline.

Comment: "Meat area" sounds weird, because "area" usually has more of a geographical sense.  I would say "meat department" or "meat section".  *Aisle* would be appropriate if it is in fact one specific aisle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a supermarket, you'd probably talk about the "aisle" (pronounced "ile").

Even though that word strictly refers to the whole row of shelves, which obviously contains more than just a single kind of product, you'd still talk about the "meat aisle" or the "chocolate aisle".

In a larger store where things aren't laid out in rows, you might talk about a "department": the menswear department, the toy department, etc.

**Edit** apparently my usage is controversial for meat; it's true in the UK, but it seems that in other countries meat is not available in aisles. You might use the word "section" or "department" in that case.

Comment: Isn't it? It is in my supermarket. Until recently they also had a separate counter where you could ask for specific cuts/weights, but those have been closed since COVID and were only a small minority of the meat sales. But I would use "counter" for that anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand what you mean. Aisles can be of shelves, fridges, or freezers. [Here](https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/NINTCHDBPICT000567844805.jpg) is an image of a refrigerated aisle with juice on one side and yogurt on the other.

Comment: Maybe where you come from, but it's just not true in the UK, I'm sorry. [Here](https://c8.alamy.com/comp/BJ2GT5/beef-on-sale-in-tesco-BJ2GT5.jpg) is another image showing a meat aisle.

Comment: Perhaps you need to edit in that the usage to which you refer is in the UK in case it varies in other anglophone countries. I agree about the UK for what it is worth.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks anyway for the answer, Daniel. I really appreciate that. However, these kind of usage seems different from countries to countries. So the way I asked originally was bad.

Comment: I'm sorry again, no it isn't. It is a row, in the middle of the store, not at the back. You can see that the yellow sign towards the back of the photo, and the fluorescent light tubes, are halfway over the refrigerated shelves, showing that there is more space to the right of them. That is not perpendicular to anything, it is an aisle. The meat aisle is stocked like any other aisle, by workers who bring the packets in trolleys to wherever the shelves are.

Comment: And [here](https://www.totallyveganbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/All-meat-fish-counters-to-be-shut-at-Sainsburys-as-pandemic-continues_TotallyVeganBuzz.jpg) is another picture showing what is definitely a meat aisle, although it's currently empty of actual meat.

Comment: Right, at this point you're just trolling. In what way is that not a meat aisle? It's a corridor in the middle of the store, between two sets of refrigerated shelves, one containing chicken and one containing beef. In other words, a meat aisle.

Comment: @Lambie Chill. Unless you make an answer, calm down please. In the U.K it **looks like** an isle, but to me it looks like a big "rack". Isle, section, department, counter, got it. Thank you for you all.

Comment: Kentaro, I have removed my comments, and as the only native AmE speaker, it is your loss not mine.

Comment: @Lambie haha Thanks. But I don't think Daniel is being rude to you. He is just hard trying to convince you I think. Aisle, got it, why did English go through GVS.

Comment: I would totally agree with Daniel Roseman for UK use, aisle & counter. However I think he would also agree that section/area is used You will find it in "The Frozen food section" Which often consists of several aisles. Then there are a few specialist areas in some supermarkets The Bakery, The Deli. etc